# Activate Mac Office 11 in Parallels VM - product key madness

Tags: microsoft-office, parallels, macos-mojave, software-activation

Yes, I know it's ancient and no longer supported.  However, I'd like to activate Mac Office 11 in a Parallels VM running Mojave.

The install was easy, I have my product key, but it wants activation by phone.  I called and entered 54 digits to the robot - but was told no go.

I have the product(s) running on an alternate system volume.  But a VM would be more convenient - and all I need to do is activate.  There must be a way.

How can I activate Mac Office 11, now that MS is shunning it?

Comment: MS says activation should still work - are you certain it can connect to the MS servers to validate the key? https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/activate-office-for-mac-2011-7d2fe037-7a2f-4381-9a65-3f40e7915b79

Comment: That's encouraging.  Where and when did MS say activation should still work?  When I try using my key the "activation server is temporarily unavailable" - permanently.  It offers phone activation as an alternative. After entering 54 digits (really?), it won't activate and hangs up. Any suggestion on where to try next?  When I follow the link you provided, it offers alternative products and a link to troubleshoot activation - which does not troubleshoot, it offers alternative products.